# Query ContentPart by fields in Orchard CMS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, orchardcms

I work in Orchard 1.4 where I have a `ProductPart` content Part that has a `IsFeatured` Boolean field. It easy to query `ProductPart` by Projection module in Orchard 1.4.

I want to write a `ProductService`, and want to query `ProductPart` where `IsFeatured` field is true like this:

```
contentManager.Query<ProductPart,ProductRecord>().Where(x=>x.IsFeatured).ToList()
```

How to get this?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. The way fields are stored prevents them from being queried in this way. You could inject IProjectionManager and use a projector query in your service. Or create a FeaturedProduct part and then query it using the ContetManager.

Comment: The `IProjectionManager` approach would have been helpful for me today. Thanks for the pointer but it seems that there's only a couple of results on the web for that class.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Query method with generics (be sure to have a using Orchard.ContentManagement)

```
var products = contentManager.Query<ProductPart, ProductPartRecord>().Where(x => x.IsFeatured).ToList()
```

Comment: IsFeatured is Boolean field:<br/>
<pre><code>ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition(typeof(ProductPart).Name, p => p.WithField("IsFeatured", f => f.OfType(typeof(BooleanField).Name))</code></pre> <br/>
<br/>
=> IsFeatured is not a property of ProductRecord => we cannot query by that way.<br/>
Any other suggestion?

Comment: This was REALLY useful, thanks! Bertrand Le Roy tells me here <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704132/retrieving-content-and-all-associated-properties-in-orchard-cms> to 'leverage the Search module', but I can't find anything on how to do that in code. Any idea?