# Retrieving content and all associated properties in Orchard CMS

Tags: linq, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

Is there a good way of programmatically pulling back a list of Content Items from Orchard?

At the moment I'm doing this, which returns a ContentPartRecord and the Title, but it's not pretty by any means:

```
public IEnumerable<LookupViewModel> Lookup(string searchText)
    {
        var items = _contentManager
            .Query<MyItemPart, MyItemPartRecord>()
            .Join<TitlePartRecord>()
            .Where(x => x.Title.Contains(searchText))
            .OrderBy(x => x.Title)
            .List();
        return items
            .Select(x => new LookupViewModel()
            {
                Text = x.Name,
                Value = x.Id.ToString()
            });
    }
```

Any pointers to related documentation would be greatly appreciated, there's very little in this regard for Orchard.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid `Contains` at all costs. It will perform horribly. Instead, leverage the Search module.

Comment: Is that this one?
Search - Version: 1.6
Install | Download
The search module enables the management of the search index and provides the front-end searching user interface.
more...
Last Updated: 10/27/2012 7:54:47 PM | Author: The Orchard Team | Downloads: 16442 | Website: http://orchardproject.net/